# How to use \nameref on a element of a tocloft custom list?

Tags: hyperref, tocloft

I am using the `tocloft` package to create a new list "question" and I would like to use `\nameref` (from the `\hyperref` package) to manually list questions (not using `\listofquestion`) at some point in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\newlistof{question}{qcnt}{List of Questions}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
    \par\vspace{5mm}\noindent%
    \refstepcounter{question}\textbf{Q\thequestion:~#1}%
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{qcnt}{question}
    {\protect\numberline{Q\thequestion}#1}
    \par
}
\section{Questions}
\label{sect:questions}

\nameref{q:bla} %prints "Questions"

\question{bla?}
\label{q:bla}
\end{document}
```

However, what I get is the name of the last section (in this case "Questions") instead of the name of the question (in this case "bla?") as an output of `\nameref{q:bla}`.

How can I fix this or what is it I am doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post a compilable document, not just fragments?

Comment: I updated the question accordingly. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not related to `tocloft` at all -- The `\newlistof` command is used for defining a list and the relevant `question` counter here, but the principal issue the correct labelling and the title capture, i.e. `\NR@gettitle`

Comment: @Christian Hupfer - I deleted my comment too soon.  From hyperref: \@ifundefined{NR@gettitle}{%
    \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%
  }{%
    \NR@gettitle{#2}%
  }%

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Oh, yes, I see -- you referred to `\@currentlabelname` -- I misread and meant `\@currentlabel`. In this case, you're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable `\nameref` to be aware of the current title, i.e. use `\NR@gettitle{#1}` inside of the `\question` command to store the information of the title into the label information, which is written to the `.aux` file. This is done by `\NR@gettitle` (actually by `\newlabel`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlistof{question}{qcnt}{List of Questions}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
  \par\vspace{5mm}\noindent%
  \refstepcounter{question}%
  \NR@gettitle{#1}%
  \textbf{Q\thequestion:~#1}%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{qcnt}{question}
  {\protect\numberline{Q\thequestion}#1}
  \par
}
\makeatletter



\begin{document}

\section{Questions}
\label{sect:questions}

\nameref{q:bla}

\question{bla?}
\label{q:bla}

\end{document}
```

Here's the corresponding `.aux` file:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Questions}{1}{section.1}}
\newlabel{sect:questions}{{1}{1}{Questions}{section.1}{}}
\@writefile{qcnt}{\contentsline {question}{\numberline {Q1}bla?}{1}{section*.1}}
\newlabel{q:bla}{{1}{1}{bla?}{section*.1}{}}
```

As can be seen, the `bla?` title is entered into the `q:bla` label. 
This is grabbed by `\nameref` later on.

[image]

Comment: @moiri: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!

Comment: Shouldn't `\makeatletter` be closed with `makeatother`?